# loop doesn't break in between calling two functions - tick tock game - please clarify

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop, user-input

**Its a tick tock game and the user has to select a position to place X or O marker in that position:**

```
def place_marker(board, marker, position):
    board[position] = marker

def player_choice(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(board, position):
        ask = int(input("Enter number between 1 and 9: "))
    return position
```

so when i call the above function:

```
position = player_choice(the_board)
place_marker(the_board, player1_marker, position)
```

**the loop doesn't place the marker in the output and keeps asking:**

Enter number between 1 and 9: 1

Enter number between 1 and 9: 2

Enter number between 1 and 9: 3

Enter number between 1 and 9: 4

Enter number between 1 and 9: 5

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't break and keeps asking you for input because the variable `position` is `0` and when ever the loop iterates the value of position doesn't change that is it is always 0 hence condition is always true.

Try something like ,

```
def player_choice(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(board, position):
        position = int(input("Enter number between 1 and 9: "))
    return position
```